# Convert 1x1 sym to float

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I attempt to convert a 1x1 sym to float in the program below below but it fails. Why?

The culprit line:

```
sol = ode45(M,[30 45],[double(H0) double(V0)]);
```

The error message:

> Error using odearguments (line 111) Inputs must be floats, namely
>   single or double.
>
> Error in ode45 (line 114) [neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir,
>   y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...
>
> Error in extra_credit_HW5_ME70 (line 60) sol = ode45(M,[30
>   45],[subs(H0) subs(V0)]);

The code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

%This program solves the rocket program by using a system of second     order
%differential which I derived (see Homework 5)

%code explanation from http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/code-examples.html?    file=/products/demos/symbolictlbx/second_order_differential_equation/solve-a-second-order-differential-equation.html


Ve=3500;
Mo=400;
Me=5;

g=9.81;

Cd=.5;
Af=.2;
R=287
T=273.15;
Patm=101325;

syms y(t);

%Note: From the hw: "Take the density of air at sea level to be 1.21
%kg/m3." I decided to model the density with an exponential function p(h)=(Patm*exp(-g*y/(R*T))/(R*T))

V = odeToVectorField(diff(y, 2) == Ve*Me/(Mo-Me.*t)-g-.5*Cd* (Patm*exp(-g*y/(R*T))/(R*T))  *diff(y).^2*Af/(Mo-Me.*t));

M = matlabFunction(V,'vars', {'t','Y'});

sol = ode45(M,[0 30],[0 0]);

x = linspace(0,30,250);
y = deval(sol,x,1);
plot(x,y);

% legend('No air resistance, air resistance');

hold on;


Mo=350;


syms y(t);

%Initial conditions for case where mass is dumped.
H0=y(end);
V0=(   (y(end)-y(end-1))  /         (x(end)-x(end-1))   );


%Note: From the hw: "Take the density of air at sea level to be 1.21
%kg/m3." I decided to model the density with an exponential function p(h)=(Patm*exp(-g*y/(R*T))/(R*T))

V = odeToVectorField(diff(y, 2) == Ve*Me/(Mo-Me.*t)-g-.5*Cd* (Patm*exp(-g*y/(R*T))/(R*T))  *diff(y).^2*Af/(Mo-Me.*t));

M = matlabFunction(V,'vars', {'t','Y'});

sol = ode45(M,[30 45],[double(H0) double(V0)]);

x = linspace(30,45,500);
y = deval(sol,x,1);
plot(x,y,'cyan');

% legend('No air resistance, air resistance');

title('Rocket height versus time for stages launch')
xlabel('time (seconds)')
ylabel('height (meters)')
```

Comment: your code does not work for me (MATLAB R2015a) at `H0=y(end);`:  `END is not a valid input for symbolic functions.`

Comment: `dbstop if error` and check what the actual values of `H0`/`V0` are.

Comment: y is a 1 by 1 symfun

Comment: @ m.s. Your version of matlab has a better error message. Do you know what the solution would be then for getting the last value in a symbolic function?